# How to dynamically order subreports in main report(jasper report)

Tags: jasper-reports

Suppose,One main report can have 9 sub-reports.
Then user can have UI from which user can order the sub-report according to his/her choice.(like,which sub-report should be displayed first and which is next and so on).
SO,how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps to achieve your requirements

1. Create 9 parameters say, **reportpath1,reportpath2,reportpath3,....reportpath9.**
2. Prompt user to enter the **order of the reports**. Based on the order pass the **respected report path to every parameter.**

Meaning, if **subreport9 is selected as 1st report**, then pass the **path of that subreport9 as reportpath1**, if **subreport8 is selected as 2nd report**, then pass the **path of that report as reportpath2** and so on

For example, if **path of subreport9 is "report/samples/subreports/subreport9"**, then set parameter **reportpath1** value as **"report/samples/subreports/subreport9"**. If path of **subreport8 is "report/samples/subreports/subreport8",** then set paramter **reportpath2** value as "**report/samples/subreports/subreport8**" and so on.

3. In report design, **create 9 subreport** and instead of hard-coding the path of each report, pass **parameter in subreportexpression** as below

For subreport1,

```
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{ReportPath1}]]></subreportExpression>
```

For subreport2,

```
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{ReportPath2}]]></subreportExpression>
```

and so on.

Hope this should solve your problem.

**Answer for getting variable from subreport**

> 1. Right click on ***subreport*** in Parent report.
> 2. Go to ***Properties***
> 3. Under ***Subreport*** session, click "**Return values**"
> 4. Add the ***subreport variable*** and map it to the ***parentreport variable***.
> 5. Then use that parentreport variable in your parent report.

Hope this should solve your another problem.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.But,I have different designs for all 9 reports.

Comment: Means I have Main report.and it does have only 9 details band for 9 different sub reports.Each band has 1 sub report starting from1 to 9.

Comment: In each subreport, you have hard-coded the report path right? Instead of hard-coding it, just follow the above step

Comment: No,I have already used parameters for giving path.And I have added 9 subreports in main report.

Comment: Can you post your sample jrxml?

Comment: Oh,Thank you so much.I have solved my problem.But I am facing another problem now.How can I get return value of  some variable in sub-report into parent-report ?

Comment: Do you wanna print the value in the parent report or you gonna use for calculation?

Comment: No,Only want to print value.No calculation.

Comment: Then no need of passing the value to the parent-report right. You can print the value in the subreport itself. In jasper, you cannot get value from subreport.

Comment: No but need to print the value calculated in sub-report into Main-report.

Comment: You can do that through the properties. I will edit my answer with those steps

Comment: But I have reports generation dynamically.Then How can i know which report is which.?

Comment: Oops in this case, create **10 variables in main report**. Create a variable in each sub report with **null or zero** in all other **8 reports** and with the **exact value on the actual report**. Return those **9 subreport variables to 9 main report variable**. And in the **10th variable** do **sum of all the above 9 variables**.

Comment: OK. I need only 5 variables in Main Report from SUb-Report.